# How can I find which values are in one pandas series but not another?

Tags: python, pandas

Given two pandas series, how can I find which elements are in 1 but not another? All elements within each series are unique.

For example, consider the following code :

```
a = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
b = pd.Series([3,2,4])
```

How would I be able to determine which elements are in Series 'a' but not in Series 'b'? In this example, the output would be [1].

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: BDW do you need `series1[series1.isin(series2)]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean what are the unique values? 
For example if you have

```
a = pd.series([1,1,1,2])
b = pd.series([1,3])
```

The output should be [1] or [1,1,1] ?

If [1] you can use:

```
set(a) - set(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set(a) - set(b)
```

> guess this should help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve this using Pandas functions specifically, then use this:

```py
a[~ a.isin(b)]
```

To explain the above expression `.isin` is a series method which returns series of True-False. `a.isin(b)` means return `True` for values in `a` which exist in `b`. And `~` is an operator which reverses each bit. So `True` becomes `False` and vice versa. Hence, we get boolean values that exist in `a` but not in `b`.

We can pass these boolean values in `a` to get values `True`.

For more details, check official documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html